# it is possible extend a uniformly continuos function f with domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ to its closure $\overline{\Omega}?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ uniformly continuos. Prove that exists $\overline{f}:\overline{\Omega}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ uniformly continuos in
$\overline{\Omega}$ such that $\overline{f}(x)=f(x)$, for all $x\in \Omega$.

Comment: Can you tell us how you’ve started and what you’ve tried?

Comment: well, first I put my eyes on a point x_0 in the boundary of Omega, then, x_0 is an accumulation point,  which implies that there exists a sequence {x_n} in Omega that converges to the point x_0. So I guess I need to manipulate the images of f under de terms of the sequence and see that the limit of the sequence of the images exists, but i'm so confused, and idk where I need to start

Comment: Big hint: Uniformly continuous functions send Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.